# map/reduce is failing on Mongoid

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mapreduce, mongoid, mongoid3

I have a class like this

```
class Todo

  TAG_REGEX = /(?:^|\s)#(\w+)/i

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::FullTextSearch

  field :desc, type: String
  field :done, type: Boolean, default: false
  field :tags, type: Array

end
```

which I'm trying to map/reduce tags like this

```
map = %Q{
  function() {
    this.tags.forEach(function(tag){
      emit(tag, { count: 1 });
    }
  }
}

reduce = %Q{
  function(key, values) {
    var result = { count: 0 };
    values.forEach(function(value) {
      result.count += value.count;
    });
    return result;
  }
}

@map = Todo .map_reduce(map, reduce).out(replace: "tags")
```

When I try to iterate over the results, I see this exception

```
The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Command
  @length=480
  @request_id=316
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[]
  @full_collection_name="todozen_development.$cmd"
  @skip=0
  @limit=-1
  @selector={:mapreduce=>"todos", :map=>"\n      function() {\n        this.tags.forEach(function(tag){\n          emit(tag, { count: 1 });\n        }\n      }\n    ", :reduce=>"\n      function(key, values) {\n        var result = { count: 0 };\n        values.forEach(function(value) {\n          result.count += value.count;\n        });\n        return result;\n      }\n    ", :query=>{}, :sort=>{"created_at"=>-1}, :out=>{:replace=>"tags"}}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error "ns doesn't exist"
```

What am I missing here?
Anyone need more information?
Thanks

Comment: I saw that Todo class is embedded in User class...so I tried this
`@tags = current_user.todos.where(:done => false).map_reduce(map,reduce).out(replace: "tags")`

But this didn't worked too
I got `undefined method 'map_reduce' for #<Mongoid::Contextual::Memory:0x007fad61bf7258>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Todo`is an embedded class...There is no way to map/reduce an embedded class...